# How can I clear unwanted titles from Window's right click on desktop?

Tags: windows-10

**I want to remove NVIDIA and Armoury shortcut from here:**

[image]

**This is a basic right click on desktop.**

I've tried googling but I only found solution for removing titles from a file's right click but not desktops' right click.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Windows Sysinternals Autoruns to manage the context menu entries.

- Download [Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)

Run Autoruns.exe as administrator and click on the `Explorer` tab. From that tab, you can delete unwanted context menu handlers.

If you prefer to delete the entries manually, read below:

To remove [NVIDIA Control Panel](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-remove-nvidia-control-panel-from-the-context-menu/) from the context menu:

1. Launch `regedit.exe` and navigate to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\NvCplDesktopContext
```

2. Right-click `NvCplDesktopContext`, click Export, and save it to a .reg file.
3. Right-click `NvCplDesktopContext` and choose Delete
4. Exit the Registry Editor.

To remove **ArmouryCrate**:

Delete key named `GameLibrary` under this branch:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and safest method for removing items from the context-menu is to
use a free GUI third-party product.

Below are some context-menu editors:

- [Easy Context Menu](https://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/)
  (the easiest to use)
- Nirsoft [ShellMenuView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html)
  and [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)